# In Solr, How to Fuzzy search and Range search in Phrase

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

All:

What I want to do is:

Search documents in SOLR which include some phrase like:

```
Episode A-1, Episode A-2,  Episode A-3...
Episode B-1, Episode B-2,  Episode B-3...
.......
Episode Z-1, Episode Z-2,  Episode Z-3...
```

The number range in each Episode could be varied, and sometimes the Episode could be Episodes.

So I wonder:
If I want to do a phrase search, how can I use some fuzzy search like

`"Episode[s]? [A-Z]{1}-\d+"`

(I am not sure if this regex is right or not, but this is basically my idea) in Regex? I think this will involves fuzzy search like Episode[s] and range search [A-Z] and maybe [1-9].

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solr 4 supports regex queries. For more details see http://www.openjems.com/solr-regex-tutorial/

Something like this should work:

`fieldName:/Episodes? [A-Z]-[1-9][0-9]{0,}/`

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried this with a simpler example, I just store 3 documents:  Ep A-1,  ep A-2, Ep B-1.
And I use /[Ee]p [AB]-[12]/ , but it does not work, could you help me with this?

Comment: You need to ensure that the fields are not tokenized and are stored as a string. Try adding `debug=true` to the request to get debug information which should help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: So you mean I need to config the title field in schema.xml to set its indexed="false"?